# Create a linked list without initializing an empty node

Tags: python, linked-list

I create a linked list using python class. But I can't manipulate the output format:

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, item=None):
        self.item = item
        self.next = None

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = Node()

    def showElements(self):
        curr = self.head
        while curr is not None:
            print(curr.item)
            curr = curr.next

    def append(self, item):
        new_node = Node(item)
        curr = self.head
        while curr.next != None:
            curr = curr.next 
        curr.next = new_node


llist = LinkedList()
llist.append(1)
print(llist.head.item) # output: None // But I want here to display 1 

llist.append(2) 
print(llist.head.next.item) # output: 1 // But I want here to display 2 

llist.showElements() # output: None 1 2 // I want only 1 2
```

Maybe my first head node create this problem. **But without initializing an empty node how could I create the reference of the next node** using the `next` attribute?

Comment: Please, avoid using `!=` when checking if an object is not `None`. Use `is not` instead. More info [here](https://realpython.com/python-is-identity-vs-equality/#comparing-the-python-comparison-operators).

Comment: I will remember it in the next time. Thanks for your suggestion @DiegoMiguel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to assign the head in the append function if there's no head already. The head was always an Empty Node

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, item=None):
        self.item = item
        self.next = None

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def showElements(self):
        curr = self.head
        while curr is not None:
            print(curr.item)
            curr = curr.next

    def append(self, item):
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = Node(item)
            return
        new_node = Node(item)
        curr = self.head
        while curr.next is not None:
            curr = curr.next
        curr.next = new_node
```

Answer (score 0):

Your append method sets **head.next** to new_node, but it never sets **head.item**, which is why you get output=None.

So with this implementation, the head doesn't store an actual element, it's just used as a starting point for the list. That's not necessarily a problem, it's one implementation choice.

You could also change the implementation to store an item in head, why not.

Whatever the choice, I would suggest implementing **first()** and **next()** methods to hide the implementation details.

Comment: **You could also change the implementation to store an item in head** It tried this, but it arises an issue with the referencing the next node. Could you help me with the *append* method? @joao